# how to pass variables between 2 php files

Tags: javascript, php, html, active-directory, ldap

I have two php files to make authentication to active directory users, i want to get the attribute `url` from it and pass this variable `$data` from `authenticate.php` to `login.php` if the function returned true to be in the location of `header("Location: *URL*");`,how can this be done?

authenticate.php:

```
<?php
  // Initialize session
  session_start();

  function authenticate($user, $password) {
  if(empty($user) || empty($password)) return false;

  // Active Directory server
  $ldap_host = "CRAMSDCR01V.cloud4rain.local";

  // connect to active directory
  $ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_host);

  $ldap_dn="OU=by-style,DC=cloud4rain,DC=local";

  // verify user and password
  if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $password)) 
  {
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn, "(cn=*)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldap));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    echo $data["url"];
    return true;    
  } 
  else 
  {
    // invalid name or password
    return false;
  }
 }
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
include("authenticate.php");

// check to see if user is logging out
if(isset($_GET['out'])) {
// destroy session
session_unset();
$_SESSION = array();
unset($_SESSION['user'],$_SESSION['access']);
session_destroy();
}

// check to see if login form has been submitted
if(isset($_POST['btn-login'])){
// run information through authenticator
if(authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
{
  // authentication passed
  header("Location: authenticate.php?$data");
  die();
 } else {
  // authentication failed
  $error = "Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights<br /-->";
}
}

// output logout success
if(isset($_GET['out'])) echo "Logout successful";
?>
```

Comment: set as session and pass it.

Comment: for example `$data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    $_SESSION['url'] = $data["url"];
    return true;`

Comment: You're including `authenticate.php` inside `login.php` so the data is already there - your issue is with variable scoping, `$data` is defined inside a function. Just have that function `return $data;` and use something like `if($authData = authenticate( ... ) { ... }` in `login.php` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**login.php**

```
<?php
include("authenticate.php");
```

That essentially acts like pasting the contents of *authenticate.php* inside *login.php* so although it's technically 2 files, it acts as if it's just the one - however `$data` is defined within the `authenticate()` function and so is only [scoped within that function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16959576/reference-what-is-variable-scope-which-variables-are-accessible-from-where-and).

In **authenticate.php** - return the data from the function

```
// verify user and password
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $user, $password)) 
{
    $result = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn, "(cn=*)") or die ("Error in search query: ".ldap_error($ldap));
    $data = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);
    // echo $data["url"]; // I assume this is just for debugging...

    // return $data from the function which should be "truthy"
    return $data;
} 
else 
{
    // invalid name or password
    return false;
}
```

In **login.php** - evaluate the return from the `authenticate()` function - since PHP is loosely typed any (non-empty) string returned by the function can be evaluated as being *"truthy"* - the only other returns you have from the function are `false` so...

```
// run information through authenticator
if($authData = authenticate($_POST['userLogin'],$_POST['userPassword']))
{
  // authentication passed
  // renamed the variable $authData just for clarity
  header("Location: authenticate.php?$authData"); 
  die();
 } 

 else {
  // authentication failed
  $error = "Login failed: Incorrect user name, password, or rights<br />";
}
```

Comment: @CD001..Thanks it worked, can you tell me how to get specific attribute from active directory?

Comment: I don't really do Active Directory sorry - but `ldap_search()` has a 4th parameter you can use to filter just to the attributes you want: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-search.php - might be what you're after...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you have `$_SESSION = array();` in login.php but if you want to pass $data from one php to another then just set it in session as

```
$_SESSION['data'] = $data;
```

ang to get it in the other file use

```
$data = $_SESSION['data'];
```